# How do I pass a parameter to RazorPage OnGet()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Using **razor pages** I am trying to build an ecommerce website for selling clothing and I want to use once page as a template to load both mens and womens pages. To test this could be done in my **_Layout.cshtml** page I use `<a asp-page="/Shop" asp-route-id="Mens" class="nav-link">Mens</a>` and then in:

### Shop.cshtml.cs

```
    [BindProperties]
public class ShopModel : PageModel
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public void OnGet(string gender)
    {
        switch (gender)
        {
            case "Mens":
                //get men page
                Status = gender;
                break;
            case "Womens":
                //get womens page
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

### Shop.cshtml

```
@page
@model ECommerce.Pages.Shop.ShopModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Shop";
}
<p>
    @Model.Status
</p>
```

When I debug the value of **gender** comes up as **null**, so status is never set. Am I going about this the wrong way? Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The parameter name is `gender`, not `id`, so it should be

```
<a asp-page="/Shop" asp-route-gender="Mens" class="nav-link">Mens</a>
```

See more about [anchor tag helper's route value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2#asp-route-value).

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to use another method other than OnGet for example OngetView you would have to put
Ver