# Razor Pages OnGet Parameter

Tags: c#, razor-pages

This is a follow-up question to this: [How do I pass a parameter to RazorPage OnGet()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132281/how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-razorpage-onget)

The issue is that the Username string never makes it to the OnGet method.

I know I'm doing this wrong - hence why I am asking for help because I'm not sure what to do.

My issue is that my Index.cshtml page needs to call the OnGet() method which initializes at startup. (the link above only details how to pass the parameter via an anchor).

I created a public string property Username.

Then in my Index.cshtml file I defined the property before the Model was declared (I also tried after).

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public List<DisplayJob> Jobs { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("username: " + Username);
            Jobs = DisplayJobService.GetListDisplayJobs(-1, 100, "", "", Username);
        }
    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@page
@{
    ViewData["Username"] = "s32xckJ1";
    Model.Username = "s32xckJ1";
}
@model IndexModel
@{

    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<p>Jobs Count: @Model.Jobs.Count()</p>
```

Comment: The `OnGet()`, as you said, gets called to initialize state needed for the page. So it's normal it still has no value. If you want to have a initial value maybe you can do it on the `.cs` file. If you need to change it on the `cshtml` file you need to add [BindProperty] to the property, this way, changes in the view will affect the model. Maybe you can ask more clearly what do you pretend.

Comment: @HenriquePombo thank you for the advice. What I want to accomplish: When the page loads, the system will recognize the username and pass that into the function to retrieve a list of all jobs that were created with that username.

Comment: Look at @AliRam's answer. After the routing you need only to change the `OnGet()` function to something like `public void OnGet(string datestart, string dateend, int referenceId, int? client)` and that should do it. Only thing left is to call the page with the parameters values. [ASP.NET Core Razor Pages Routing With parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57525718/asp-net-core-razor-pages-routing-with-parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have discovered, as far as routing is concerned.

```
@page "{datestart}/{dateend}/{referenceid:int=0}/{client?}"
```

Might be an odd way but you can add an addtional root by using the AddPageRoute method.

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
   options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/details", "{datestart}/{dateend}/{client?}");
});
```

Use Attribute [httpget]
get parameter by viewmodel.
for send to razor cshtml can use viewbag.